# How display multiple instances of a view using Prism and Unity

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, unity-container

I'm working on a .Net application using WPF, Unity and Prism 4. The application will consist of a shell with multiple views on tab pages. The application relies heavily on a module named SystemTreeModule that contains the `SystemTreeView` which will appear in many places.

I have just finished of my first view where I defined a region named "SystemTreeRegion". In the SystemTreeModule I registered an instance of my `SystemTreeView` with that region. Works like a charm! The `SystemTreeView` type is discovered using Unity's autodiscovery-feature (so it is not registered explicitly):

```
public void Initialize()
{
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("SystemTreeRegion", () => _container.Resolve<SystemTreeView>());
}
```

Now it's time to start the work on the second module where I want to use the `SystemTreeView`. I felt really confident when I created a region named "SystemTreeRegion" in the new view, but it fails with the following exception:

> An exception occurred while creating a region with name 'SystemTreeRegion'. 
>       The exception was: System.ArgumentException: Region with the given name is already registered: SystemTreeRegion

So I have both googled and searched StackOverflow for answers but I haven't been able to figure out how you are supposed to do this!

I can't even tell if I'm just missing some detail or if I'm conceptually way off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not way off conceptually. Providing a view by means of a module is quite OK. But keep in mind that you can have only one view named "SystemTreeRegion" in your application, because otherwise Prism's region manager won't know which view you want to access.

Taking that into account - you are conceptually wrong if you try to register a view to a region's name and hope that the view will appear in every region carrying that name. You can only register views to a region.

So simply ensure that every region has its own unique name, and then register the view you need for that region and you will be fine.

Comment: Just a clarification on your last sentance - do you mean; "So simply ensure that every **region** has its own unique name [...]"?

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for pointing that out. Of course every **region** is meant.

Comment: Then I'm conceptually wrong. :-/  Lets say I create unique region names for all regions where I want to see my SystemTreeView. Would you write the code for registering the view for all regions in the SystemTreeModule or in each module defining a region where you want the SystemTreeView to appear?

Comment: In each module where I want the `SystemTreeView` to appear - because the SystemTreeModule knows nothing about dependant modules. (NB: Ensure you configure the module dependencies correctly, so that the SystemTreeModule gets loaded before the others do)

Comment: So I would write _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("SystemTreeRegionX", () => _container.Resolve<SystemTreeView>()); in every module that expects a SystemTreeView (the region name SystemTreeRegionX varies between modules). That implies a reference from each module to the SystemTreeModule and that feels "bad". How do you do it with common views that appear in many places - create an interface and registering it with Unity, _container.RegisterType<ISystemTreeView, SystemTreeView>();? We will actually test different implementations of the SystemTreeView so we want it to be easily exchangable.

Comment: Using an interface would be the way to go here. That way - as you have correctly pointed out - you won't need a reference to the SystemTreeModule. Additionally you can replace the `ISystemTreeView` for testing purposes.